# Bootstrap controlling how columns stack

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to do the following:

Medium Screens

|...img...||...detail...||...detail...||...detail...|

.............|...detail...||...detail...||...detail...|

Small Screens

|...img...||...detail...|

.............|...detail...|

.............|...detail...|

.............|...detail...|

.............|...detail...|

.............|...detail...|

.............|...detail...|

This is my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 pull-left">Map</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 pull-right">detail</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 pull-right">detail</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 pull-right">detail</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 pull-right">detail</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also the img can be resized just as long as the format of the columns stays the same. I apoligize for the messy diagram (not enough points to post a picture...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first column will contain the image, the second one the details. In the second column you can make several rows.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Map</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">detail</div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">detail</div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">detail</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The nested row approach is great, but remove the pull-right.  It's unnecessary.